# Context.provider throw error when wrapping my app component with it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

My app is work just fine until I add this line of code <AuthContext.provider> and wrap the app component with it:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

here is my app

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Users from "./pages/Users";
import MainNavigation from "./common/Navigation/MainNavigation";
import UserPlaces from "./pages/places/UserPlaces";
import NewPlace from "./pages/places/NewPlace";
import UpdatePlace from "./pages/places/UpdatePlace";
import Auth from "./pages/Users/Auth";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/auth-context";

const App = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  const login = useCallback(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
  }, []);

  const logout = useCallback(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.provider
      value={{ isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn, login: login, logout: logout }}
    >
      <Router>
        <MainNavigation />
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Users} exact />
            <Route path="/:userId/places" component={UserPlaces} exact />
            <Route path="/places/new" component={NewPlace} exact />
            <Route path="/places/:pId" component={UpdatePlace} exact />
            <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} exact />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </Router>
    </AuthContext.provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and this is the auth-context file

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});
```

could not know what the problem with the context

Answer (score 1):

Try using `AuthContext.Provider` instead:

```
// Not AuthContext.provider
<AuthContext.Provider value={...}>
      ...
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Yes, that helps. it's a stupid mistake. Thank you so much for your answer :)